# JSON field naming support in Google JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, gson

How can I parse below response using [Google Json](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

```
{
"code": 1,
"data": {
    "0": {
        "name": "test",
        "expirationDate": "-1",
        "masterDate": "31\/5\/2013",            
    },
    "message": "my message"
}
}
```

I tried with this....

```
public class Test {

public int code;
public Data data;

public class Data {
    @SerializedName("0")
    public Promo customName;
}

public class Promo {
    public String name;
    public String expirationDate;
    public String masterDate;       
}
```

It's not working.

Comment: It worked..  Sorry Guys

Answer (score 0):

Your `Data` class is missing the `message` variable:

```
public class Data {
    @SerializedName("0")
    public Promo customName;

    public String message;
}
```

Comment: It's not matter. If you don't use any item then google json skip them.